# Protect Word Document using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to use vba to protect my word document.

Indeed, it is possible but I've searched on how to unprotect the document through this link :
*http://www.aurelp.com/2015/04/01/how-to-unlock-a-microsoft-word-document-step-by-stepsolved/*

Is there any other way on how to successfully protect the document from unauthorized user?

Answer (score 3):

Using VBA, I believe you'd be looking for the `protect` method:

```
Application.ActiveDocument.Protect wdAllowOnlyRevisions, password:="password"
```

With `protect`, you can specify the type of protection, the password, and various components of the protection (style lock, resetting of form fields, etc.).
More on `protect` can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220366(v=office.11).aspx).

Likewise, VBA has a similar method for unprotecting a Word document, if you know the password. This is the aptly named `unprotect` method.

```
Application.ActiveDocument.Unprotect "password"
```

More on `unprotect` can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221210(v=office.11).aspx).